# Failed to connect to server. Error: 0x8007000E

Tags: windows-installer

A client is getting this error in the log file when he tries to run my installer.

```
Failed to connect to server. Error: 0x8007000E
```

The installer works fine when I test it on my own machine.

Here is the complete log file

```
=== Verbose logging started: 10/29/2013 9:12:29 Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.7601.00 Calling process: C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (20:FC) [09:12:29:171]: Font created. Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (20:FC) [09:12:29:171]: Font created. Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (20:F8) [09:12:29:203]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (20:F8) [09:12:29:203]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (20:F8) [09:12:29:203]: ******* RunEngine:
******* Product: C:\portableApps\Tick2Disk6.1.4.msi
******* Action:
******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (20:F8) [09:12:29:218]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (c) (20:F8) [09:12:29:250]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer 3: 2
MSI (c) (20:F8) [09:12:29:250]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'C:\portableApps\Tick2Disk6.1.4.msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (c) (20:F8) [09:12:29:250]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DigitalSignature 3: -2147287038
MSI (c) (20:F8) [09:12:29:250]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\portableApps\Tick2Disk6.1.4.msi is not digitally signed
MSI (c) (20:F8) [09:12:29:250]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\portableApps\Tick2Disk6.1.4.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (c) (20:F8) [09:12:29:640]: Failed to connect to server. Error: 0x8007000E

MSI (c) (20:F8) [09:12:29:640]: MainEngineThread is returning 1601
=== Verbose logging stopped: 10/29/2013 9:12:29 ===
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The client's installer service was OK. However, his anti-virus software was interfering!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Your question was "What server is it trying to connect to?".  I answered that.

Comment: @ravenspoint you really should change the accepted answer as Christopher stated.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter has misread my question.  The error msg was "Failed to connect to server"  My question is: why does this error msg appear?  The answer is: it was caused by the client's anti-virus software.

Answer (score 10):

MSIEXEC.exe is both a client (the command you type in a command prompt) and a server ( the part that gets hosted as the Windows Installer Service ).  This error means the server failed to start and/or the client failed to connect to it.

From an elevated command prompt try:

```
net stop msiserver

msiexec /unreg

msiexec /regserver

net start msiserver
```

Then try running our installer again.  You'll have to do more troubleshooting of this broken machine if it still doesn't work.  This is unlikely to mean there is anything wrong with the MSI you created it's just a corrupted windows on the target machine.

Comment: Thanks.  I will get the client to try this.

Comment: The better google search is "windows installer 1601"  another possible remedy is: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942288

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  The client's installer service was OK.  However, his anti-virus software was interfering!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The section that says "**Software Restriction policy**" could indicate a restriction enforced by **group policy** from **active directory**? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457006.aspx.

Broken link detected (March 2018), resurrecting via Wayback Machine: [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310791](https://web.archive.org/web/20120831063338/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310791).