# MSI installer cannot install files

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I have a few problems trying to install .msi files in my computer. I have a few executables that I want to run but I can't install them running them as administrator, I normally get the error: **Windows installer service could not be accessed.**

I tried to open them on command line to get the log from the 2 different MSI files and I get almost an identical result from both logs:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 1/30/2014  13:38:48  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.7601.00  Calling process: C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (D0:30) [13:38:48:733]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (D0:30) [13:38:48:733]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (D0:60) [13:38:48:739]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (D0:60) [13:38:48:740]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (D0:60) [13:38:48:740]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\Users\TR\Downloads\komodo.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (D0:60) [13:38:48:746]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (c) (D0:60) [13:38:48:776]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer 3: 2 
MSI (c) (D0:60) [13:38:48:849]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'C:\Users\TR\Downloads\komodo.msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (c) (D0:60) [13:38:48:849]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DigitalSignature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (D0:60) [13:38:48:849]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\Users\TR\Downloads\komodo.msi is not digitally signed
MSI (c) (D0:60) [13:38:48:850]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\Users\TR\Downloads\komodo.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (c) (D0:60) [13:38:48:854]: Failed to connect to server. Error: 0x8007000E

MSI (c) (D0:60) [13:38:48:861]: MainEngineThread is returning 1601
=== Verbose logging stopped: 1/30/2014  13:38:48 ===
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's also a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659957/failed-to-connect-to-server-error-0x8007000e

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: See this answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22168024/129130

Answer (score 1):

Try executing these commands with admin rights after booting your computer in safe mode:

1. Boot to safe mode, launch an admin rights command prompt
2. %windir%\system32\msiexec.exe /unregister
3. %windir%\system32\msiexec.exe /regserver
4. %windir%\syswow64\msiexec.exe /unregister
5. %windir%\syswow64\msiexec.exe /regserver
6. Reboot, launch Windows normally

Comment: Generally you need to post some explanation of what it is those commands are doing.

Comment: These commands will re-register the Windows Installer Service (COM objects). I don't think there will be any messages displayed even if the registration is successful. It is worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Open CMD as administrator

Go to the .msi parent folder for example Downloads

Inside downloads folder type xxxxx.msi

And your installation will run as administrator and you can install your file without problem

Comment: I follow those steps and it works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch an MSI, a client process is started (msiexec.exe).  This is why you see all these (c) entries in the logs.

There is also an on demand windows service (which also happens to be msiexec.exe)  The client autostarts this service and connects to it.  This is failing.   You can try to see if the service will start manually. If not, try unregistering, reregistering and restarting the service.  Examples can be seen [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mpoulson/archive/2005/11/30/498586.aspx).

Comment: See this dupe for a tip about antivirus products. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659957/failed-to-connect-to-server-error-0x8007000e

Comment: I already did those steps and it doesn't work, i get the same results from the log. I also checked that dupe but even when i turned off my anti and firewall the problem still persist.

Comment: It generally helps if you write down what steps you've already tried.  Sorry try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324516/en-us  If that doesn't work, either reinstall windows, try upgrading to a newer MSI version or open a ticket with MSFT.

Answer (score 0):

This might be specific to that system. Perhaps it's an AV issue or an issue with the OS. If you can create a clean virtual machine OS and your install works there then you'd know it's that specific system.

It's a common error, and this may apply, but I don't know that it should be done on newer OS versions:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324516/en-us

Answer (score 0):

##### Problem:

I faced similar issue while installing Microsoft Application Error Reporting (dw20sharedamd64.msi) for Dynamics 365 CRM 9.0 on-premise on Windows Server 2019 Standard and resolved using below steps:

##### Root Cause:

MSI didn't have trusted certificate registered on server due to which following error was generated "Error occured when checking signature of "dw20sharedamd64.msi":  Error 0x800b0109 reported."

##### Resolution:

•  Make sure you are local admin on server.
•  Right click on .msi (in this case dw20sharedamd64.msi) go to Properties then click on tab “Digital Signatures”.
•  From “Signatures list”, select the signature and click on “Details”.
•  Select “View Certificate” then go to tab “Certification Path” select Microsoft Root Authority and click “View Certificate”.
•  Select tab “Details” and click “Copy to File…” then Next and give a name “root”.
•  Navigate to “root.cer” path and right click and click “Install Certificate”.
•  Select “Current Machine” and Browse the path of store “Trusted Root Certification Authority” and Next the Finish.
•  Now try MIS installer again, surely will work.

[image]

Comment: Please format your answer for legibility. The wall of test is really hard to read.